# не знаю как назвать body background для js

Tags: javascript, html, background

Eсть задача сделать интерактивный фон для сайта, чтобы он чуть двигался от движения мыши. Что-то вроде [этого](http://krylia-perm.ru/). Я знаю, что есть тема именно с этим сайтом, от туда я JS код и взяла.

Изначально я сделала так:

```js
$(".bg").interactive_bg();
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

body {
  overflow: auto;
}

.bg {
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg" data-ibg-bg="img/mp.jpg"></div>
```

Все работало, но проблема была в том, что все что я писала дальше уходило за фон.

Я решила сделать фон прям в боди через CSS:

```
body {
  background: url(img/mp.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Теперь ничего не работает, перепробовала кучу вариантов как можно обратиться к  этому `background`, но пока что все безуспешно.[image]

Можно ли вообще делать так как я хочу, если можно, то как, и как обратиться к `background`?

Comment: Где вы взяли скрипт для функции `interactive_bg`? Посмотрите, там еще должны быть специальные стили для `<div class="bg" data-ibg-bg="img/mp.jpg"></div>`. Их тоже надо применить.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko Взяла здесь http://www.cyberforum.ru/javascript/thread1371466.html , там сказали что это называется  готовый плагин "jQuery Interactive BG". Вначале вопроса есть стили для .bg . Но проблема не в этом, а в том что сейчас все не работает, из-за того что я не знаю как обратиться к body background.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko вначале не поняла вас наверное, в head  у меня еще прописано   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.onextrapixel.com/examples/interactive-background/js/jquery.interactive_bg.js"></script>

Comment: С `background` он скорее всего работать не будет) На сайте, который вы указали, у `.bg2` есть особые стили. Посмотрите на них.

Answer (score 0):

Оказалось: плагин jQuery Interactive BG работает только, если он как фон и контента на нем нет. Через body тоже нельзя было сделать. Очень хороший человек помог решить проблему  с помощью parallax.js

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">  -->
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<!--        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.onextrapixel.com/examples/interactive-background/js/jquery.interactive_bg.js"></script>-->
<!--        <script src="js/parallax.js"></script>-->
        `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/parallax/3.1.0/parallax.min.js"></script>

        <style type="text/css">
            html, body {
                height: 100%;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0; 
                overflow: hidden; }
        body {   overflow: auto;
                 text-align: center;
            }
        .bg {    width: 105%;
            height: 105%;
                 background:url(img/mp.jpg) center center no-repeat; 
            background-size: cover;
/*
            position: absolute;
            top: 5px;
            left: 5px;
*/
            
            
            }

        .content-wrapper{
                position: absolute;
                top: 0;
                left: 0;
                right: 0;
                margin: auto;
                min-height: 100vh;
                width: 100vw;
                z-index: 2;
              }

        .bg-wrapper {
            position: fixed;
            top: -30px;
            left: -30px;
            z-index: 1;
            width: 100vw;
            height: 100vh;
            
                        }
        </style>

       
    </head>
<body>
 

<div class="bg-wrapper" id="scene" >
    
     <div class="bg" data-depth="0.2"></div>
     
    
  

   
   </div>
    

<div class="content-wrapper">
    <h1>TEXT TEXT TEXT </h1>
    <div class="info">
    <a href="#">Контакты</a>
        <a href="#">Контакты</a>
        <a href="#">Контакты</a>
        <a href="#">Контакты</a>
    </div>

</div>
    
    
<!--  box-shadow: -10px 0 20px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.3); для футера-->

 <script type="text/javascript">
        
//     var parallax = new Parallax($("#parallax"));
      var scene = document.getElementById('scene');
      var parallaxInstance = new Parallax(scene);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Спасибо всем за ответы:)